# All combinations for specific arrangement- python

Tags: python, list, combinations

Id like to compute all the combination for different, specific arrangements and put them in separate list.

The general form of an element is like `[[a#, b#], [a#, b#]]`, where the # can take on numbers from 1-4.

The goal is to make a list of all the possible elements that can result for a certain form/arrangement. like if the form is `[[ai, bi], [ai, bi]]`, where i can be a value from 1-4. 
The output for this form would look like this,

```
A=[[[a1, b1], [a1, b1]], [[a2, b2], [a2, b2]], [[a3, b3], [a3, b3]], [[a4, b4], [a4, b4]]]
```

Other i form is `[[ai, bj], [ai, bj]]`, where i and j can be value from 1-4 but i≠j, and the outcome would be a list of all the possibilities. Similarly, the form could be [[ai, bj], [ak, bj]], where i, j, k can ba values from 1-4 but i≠j≠k

Im not even sure how to approach this so there isn't any code Ive started on so Im just looking for input or advice on how to work this out.

Comment: Check out the doc on combinations():
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your example shows, I don't think you want to use any combination. A formatting may work for you.

```
z = []
for i in range(1, 5): 
    x = [] 
    y = [] 
    x.append('a{}'.format(i)) 
    x.append('b{}'.format(i)) 
    y.append(x) 
    y.append(x)
    z.append(y)
```

Comment: Hey this is great, thanks! Just a fallow up, is there anyway to not have the outputs in quotations? As of now its gives out [[['a1', 'b1'], ['a1', 'b1']], and I'm wondering if theres a way to make it like [[[a1, b1], [a1, b1]],

Comment: The quote shows that these are strings. So if you are interested in strings, you must have to use ' or ". You can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) about standard types .

Comment: Im not really thinking of them as string rather symbols or variable? If that makes sense . Would there be a way to change it to not be strings anymore?

Answer (score 0):

```py
A = [[[f'a{i}', f'b{i}']] * 2 for i in range(1, 5)]
```

For earliear versions of python that don't support f strings

```py
A = [[['a' + str(i), 'b' + str(i)]] * 2 for i in range(1, 5)]
```

Comment: Hey, sorry this is giving out an invalid syntax error. Also, what are the f's about. And for the second case when the j comes in would i format it the same as done here? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You can read about f strings [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Comment: Thanks alot. I havent been able to figure out how to incorporate j, k, l into this yet. Would you have any input.